# git trying to push already deleted file from local

Tags: git

I have added my code by

```
git add .
```

Now I have committed my code by

```
got commit -m "Added Filter"
```

Now when I have tried to push code by

```
git push
```

I have found that there is one file named **java_pid12312.hprof** whose size is more than 1 GB and so I have stopped git by 
**Control + C**

Now I have deleted that **java_pid12312.hprof** file from finder & from trash in Mac.

Now I tried again to push file hopping that file will not upload but still git is showing me to upload one large file, I have checked my whole source code there is no file whose size is more than 200 kb.

I thought that it might be in cache, so I have used below command to remove it from cache

```
git rm --cached java_pid12312.hprof
```

But it shows me error message like below

```
fatal: pathspec 'java_pid12312.hprof' did not match any files
```

How it is possible? I am sure that it is still trying to push **java_pid12312.hprof** which I have already deleted, is there any idea?

Comment: If you check out the last commit (git checkout HEAD^) can you see the file then on the filesystem?

Comment: Git does not push *files*. Git pushes—and stores—entire *commits* at a time. If you are sending a commit that contains a 1GB file, that will take a while.

Comment: Yes it has taken so much time while performing command git add .

Comment: @JamesHalsall, Yes in history of my git it shows me that file

Comment: If it has not pushed to the remote yet, then you can rewrite history with `git reset --soft HEAD^1`, then remove the file, commit again, and then push

Comment: But JamesHalsall, right now I have done lots of changes, should I have to backup that first?, because by resetting HEAD, my current changes will also be deleted right?

Comment: Not if you use the `--soft` flag, it won't remove files on disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the file has already been committed, and even though you have now removed the file it still exists in your history.

To remove it from your history, providing the push to the remote has not yet happened, you can do the following:

1. `git reset --soft HEAD^` (this will rewind by 1 commit, but preserve your files on disk, so you won't lose anything)
2. `rm -f java_pid12312.hprof`
3. `git commit -m "New commit"`
4. `git push`

Comment: I can still see the same error. Tried exactly as you've suggested. Any workaround for this ?